# Erro de sintaxe SQL - Python

Tags: mysql, python

Tenho um aplicativo flask no qual uma das funcionalidades (log_request) é gravar dados de um formulário em uma base de dados SQL. Ao executar a def log_request, no entanto, tenho um erro acusando sintaxe incorreta. Já revisei várias vezes e não consegui identificar tais erros na def:

```
def log_request(req: 'flask_request', res: str) -> None:

        dbconfig = {'user': 'vsearch',
                'password': 'vsearchpasswd',
                'host': '127.0.0.1',
                'database': 'vsearchlogDB',}

        import mysql.connector

        conn = mysql.connector.connect(**dbconfig)
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        _SQL = '''insert into log
                (phrase, letters, ip, browser_string, results)
                values
                (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s,)'''
        
        cursor.execute(_SQL,   (req.form['phrase'],
                                req.form['letters'],
                                req.remote_addr,
                                req.user_agent.browser,
                                res, ))

        conn.commit()        
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
```

Como podem ver a estrutura da minha db está conforme chamei (tabela 'log' dentro da db 'vsearchlogDB':
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem certeza de que deve ter esta `,` em `res, ))`?

Comment: Tirei a vírgula, mesmo assim acusa erro de sintaxe...

Comment: Copia e cola o erro aqui

Comment: Tem uma vírgula extra no fim dos valores da query também: `(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s,)'''`

Comment: Era isso mesmo Lucas, obrigado!